# Sorting the CSV based on Unix timestamp

Tags: sort, csv, time

I have a large number of CSV files, each file having multiple numeric columns. The first column is Unix timestamp. How can I sort such file? Thank you.

An example row of the file as below:

```
1376317246; 4;  11703.99824;    10477.029091173334; 89.51666666666667;  6.7108864E7;    2.0937962933333334E7;   0.0;    1.4;    235.53333333333333; 3.8666666666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a CSV file if it looks like that.

```
sort -t";" filename
```

should work. This will sort on all columns. If that's unappealing, then [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507928/342951) should suit you.

From the docs:

> ```
>    -t, --field-separator=SEP
>           use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
> ```

Comment: Specifying the delimiter is of no use here as you don't use it. That would be useful in `sort -t ';' -k2,2` to sort based on the second field. But not here we're you're sorting based on the full content of the line.

Comment: Although I missed that, @StéphaneChazelas It's still necessary because `;` is larger than digits. So if there's a row whose first field is `137631724` (this is the value in the example without the trailing `6`), sorting on the whole content will place this below the `1376317246`, which would be incorrect.

Comment: Still, `-t` will make no  difference. You'd need `sort -t ';' -k1,1` for it to make a difference. But here, all you need and want is `sort -n`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use *[sort](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)*

```
sort --field-separator=';' --key=1 yourCSVfile.csv
```

if you need to create a new sorted file just add an output file:

```
sort --field-separator=';' --key=1 yourCSVfile.csv > sortedCSVfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use sort with following option:

- `-g` (--general-numeric-sort) for numeric sort just in case, because default sorting mechanism is alphanimeric and sorting {9..11} would result in 10 11 9.

```
sort -g filename
```

Comment: you're right. I'll edit the answer. So -g would be sufficient.